# Assert\Expression gives Variable Not Valid around position 2

Tags: forms, symfony, field, assert

I have a form. I am trying to assert that if one field is not null, then another field must also not be null. Trying to do this with Symfony annotations as I don't want the code in the controller and was told this would be a good way to do it.

I have tried using an Assert\Expression, however I keep getting various errors on the field that I am checking. It's slightly concerning that it says `Variable` when I need it to be referring to a field.

```
                // The field that I want to check if it is null
                'activeTestData',
                null,
                [
                    'label' => 'form.label.active_test_data',
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                // The field that can't be null if the activeTestData field is not null
                'activeTestDataUnit',
                ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'form.label.active_test_data_unit',
                    'required' => false,
                    'choices' => [
                        'form.label.active_test_please_select' => '',
                        'Byte(s)' => 'b',
                        'Kilobyte(s)' => 'k',
                        'Megabyte(s)' => 'm',
                        'Gigabyte(s)' => 'g',
                    ],
                    // Where I am having the issue
                    'constraints' => [
                        new Assert\Expression([
                           'expression' => "!activeTestData == null",
                            'message' => 'Please enter a unit for active test data'
                        ]),
                    ],
```

I want a FORM error for when there is nothing in activeTestDataUnit but there is something in activeTestData. Unfortunately I get a symfony error:
`Variable "activeTestData" is not valid around position 2 for expression !activeTestData == null`.

Comment: Have you tried `'expression' => "!this.activeTestData == null"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for this situation would be the following:
`"!this.getParent().get('activeTestData')->getData() == null"`

You can see more examples and details on [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html#basic-usage).

I updated my answer. In this context "this" is a Form object of a "activeTestDataUnit" field. So to check for a "activeTestData" value you have go to to the parent and then get a correct child.

As of Symfony 4.1 you can pass your custom values to the "values" argument and avoid all of this clutter, by passing `$builder->getData()`. See here for the more information on [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html#values)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tried it and got this in response `Unable to call method "getActiveTestData" of object "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".
` Unfortunatly this code is in the form type, not the class entity, will see if the class is instantiated and see if I can call it like `class_name.getActiveTestData() == null`. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry to be a bit more specific, the activeTestData bit is a **field** in the from, and also the name of a **property** in the entity that the field refers to.